# Can anyone explain this bizarre behavior in jQuery next?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works:

```
<div class="xpav">
    Create
</div>
<div class="apr" style="display: none;">
    sometext
</div>

<script>
$('.xpav').click(function() {
    $(this).next(".apr").slideDown("fast");    
})
</script>
```

It doesn't:

```
<div class="xpav">
    Create
</div>
<br />
<div class="apr" style="display: none;">
    sometext
</div>

<script>
$('.xpav').click(function() {
    $(this).next(".apr").slideDown("fast");    
})
</script>
```

Why 
 breaks it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) only looks at the element that comes after the given element, *then* checks that element against the selector if it's provided. In your second example, since the `br` is there and doesn't have the `apr` class, it isn't picked up. From the API docs:

> **Description:** Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Your second example requires the use of [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) instead to search through all the next siblings:

```
$('.xpav').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".apr").slideDown("fast");    
});
```

To pick up only the first `.apr` that's matched, use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq):

```
$('.xpav').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".apr").eq(0).slideDown("fast");    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

under my impression `next()` only works if the sibling objuect is the same DOM tage,

what does work is:

```
$('.xpav').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).next(".apr"));
    $(this).siblings(".apr").slideDown("fast");    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly that what the documentations says: "Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

Because `next()` takes you to the immediate next DOM element which is `<br />`. Why not use this:

`$(".apr").slideDown("fast");`

Comment: Because then every single `.apr` will animate?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you are using the `next()` method in your code.  The next DOM element from `$('.xpav')` in the second version of your code is a `<br />`, and since that doesn't match the filter, it doesn't slide anything down!

If you want it to work, you should consider using `nextAll()` instead of `next()`, as the latter ONLY gets the very next DOM element, where the former gets all siblings that are after itself in the DOM.